# Installing Linux without disabling Bitlocker encryption

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, ubuntu, encryption

**Is there a way to install and dual boot Ubuntu / Fedora along with Windows 11 without disabling bitlocker encryption?**

##### Possible approach

The other solution for continuing to use Bitlocker extending from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305270/bitlocker-is-blocking-ubuntu-20-04-installation-in-a-dual-boot-system-with-windo):

1. Disable bitlocker
2. Install Ubuntu
3. Renable bitlocker
4. Use dislocker and mount encrypted drive as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617950/use-windows-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-on-ubuntu).

###### Problem with the approach

1. I have an OEM version on Windows Home and bitlocker once disabled, *cannot* be re-enabled as mentioned [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/re-enable-bitlocker-on-windows-10-home/d4c7924c-29f6-4233-a7ed-434047c2e475) and also from personal experience.
2. And if I do not disable bitlocker ubuntu may not be able to proceed. [image]

Any suggestions ?

> PS: Posting here since there may be a cross platform fix for this.

Comment: Does the disk currently have enough "unallocated space" for Ubuntu to create its own partitions? If not, can you shrink the Windows partition via `diskmgmt.msc` from within Windows itself? That's the most important thing the Ubuntu installer won't be able to do from "outside" to an encrypted volume.